# Selenium can't find class element from dynamic web page

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

from twilio.rest import Client
from datetime import datetime
import datefinder
import os

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

url = 'https://www.recreation.gov/permits/233262/registration/detailed-availability?type=overnight-permit'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

title = ""
text = ""
campsites = ""


waiter = webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="per-availability-main"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/button[2]')))
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="per-availability-main"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/button[2]')
element.click()
time.sleep(0.3)
element.click()
time.sleep(0.4)

waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="per-availability-main"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/label/span')))
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="per-availability-main"]/div[1]/div[3]/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/label/span')
element.click()
time.sleep(0.5)

waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'rec-grid-grid-cell available')))
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'rec-grid-grid-cell available')
time.sleep(4)
```

So this code is to eventually compile a list of available permits for a given date for me to quickly find out which I want to do. It clicks 2 users and selects "no" for the guided trip. This reveals a grid, which shows the available sites. The first 2 steps work completely fine. It stops working when it tries to work with the grid.

I'm trying to locate available sites with the class name "rec-grid-grid-cell available"
I have also tried locating anything on that grid by XPATH and it can't seem to find anything. Is there a special way to deal with grids that appear after a few clicks?

If you need more information, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot pass multiple css class names to `By.CLASS_NAME`.

So you can do either:

```
available_cells_css = ".rec-grid-grid-cell.available"
available_cells = waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, available_cells_css)))
```

or

```
available_cells_xpath = "//div[@class='rec-grid-grid-cell available']"
available_cells = waiter.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, available_cells_xpath)))
```